# How to resolve thee error "Error in mde(x): 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double' Traceback:"?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a .tsv file, similar to the example given bellow.

```
       index    GLWSKIKEVGKEAAKA  GLFDIIKKIAESI GLLDIVKKVVGAFGSL GLFDIVKKVVGALGSL 
GLWSKIKEVGKEAAKA    33  7   10  11  9   9   11  10
GLFDIIKKIAESI       7   13  8   9   8   9   11  11
GLLDIVKKVVGAFGSL    10  8   16  14  13  11  11  10
GLFDIVKKVVGALGSL    11  9   14  16  14  12  12  11
```

file read perfectly:

```
m <- read.table("out_1.csv", sep=",",header=TRUE, row.names='index')
```

trying to build a network graph using the library given bellow.

```
library(igraph)
ig <- graph.adjacency(m, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
```

raised an error

```
Error in mde(x): 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Traceback:

1. graph.adjacency(m, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)
2. graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted, 
 .     diag = diag)
3. `mode<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "double")
```

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The help pages say you need a square adjacency matrix.

You have a **`data.frame`** with **8** columns and **4** rows in your example. 
(I assume you have empty columns in your header that do not show up in your pasted text.)

This would work:

```r
m <- as.matrix(read.table("out_1.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, row.names='index')[, 1:4])
library(igraph)
ig <- graph.adjacency(m, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
ig
#> IGRAPH 80e1470 UNW- 4 10 -- 
#> + attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
#> + edges from 80e1470 (vertex names):
#>  [1] GLWSKIKEVGKEAAKA--GLWSKIKEVGKEAAKA GLWSKIKEVGKEAAKA--GLFDIIKKIAESI   
#>  [3] GLWSKIKEVGKEAAKA--GLLDIVKKVVGAFGSL GLWSKIKEVGKEAAKA--GLFDIVKKVVGALGSL
#>  [5] GLFDIIKKIAESI   --GLFDIIKKIAESI    GLFDIIKKIAESI   --GLLDIVKKVVGAFGSL
#>  [7] GLFDIIKKIAESI   --GLFDIVKKVVGALGSL GLLDIVKKVVGAFGSL--GLLDIVKKVVGAFGSL
#>  [9] GLLDIVKKVVGAFGSL--GLFDIVKKVVGALGSL GLFDIVKKVVGALGSL--GLFDIVKKVVGALGSL
```